# copying data from 1:N relationship into single table (effectively)

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

We have 2 tables in 1:N relationship. Item and it's custom properties, for example.

```
CREATE TABLE item (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE property (
  id    BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  oneFK BIGINT REFERENCES item (id),
  key   CHARACTER VARYING(5),
  value CHARACTER VARYING(5)
);
```

lets have some demo data:

```
INSERT INTO item VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO property VALUES
  (1, 1, 'key1', 'val1'),
  (2, 1, 'key2', 'val2'),
  (3, 1, 'key3', 'val3');
```

after we have some millions rows in these tables, it's requested to 'export' them to another table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE flat (
  id   BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  key1 CHARACTER VARYING(5),
  key2 CHARACTER VARYING(5),
  key3 CHARACTER VARYING(5)
);
```

so naive insert could look like:

```
INSERT INTO flat (id, key1, key2, key3)
  SELECT
    i.id,
    (SELECT p.value
     FROM property p
     WHERE p.oneFK = i.id AND p.key = 'key1'),

    (SELECT p.value
     FROM property p
     WHERE p.oneFK = i.id AND p.key = 'key2'),

    (SELECT p.value
     FROM property p
     WHERE p.oneFK = i.id AND p.key = 'key3')
  FROM item i;
```

but there would be like 5 nested selects, each of them in quite big table. So I don't like this at all. There was different 'proposal', which I like even less, doubt it will actually perform better, and find it little bit ridiculous:

```
INSERT INTO flat
  SELECT
    i.id,
    --lots of other properties
    max(CASE WHEN key = 'key1'
      THEN 'key1'
        ELSE NULL END)
  --so on.
  FROM item i
    JOIN property p ON i.id = p.oneFK
  GROUP BY i.id --, lots of other properties
```

so what would be actually recommended and efficient way to perform this task? Ideally in generic sql, oracle/postgres specific (ideally both) is also fine.

Comment: Oracle and Postgres are different databases...which one are you using here (you have tagged both)?  You are asking for a 'pivot' by the way...it's one of the more common questions on stack under the SQL tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second "proposal" is probably the way to do this (using conditional aggregation to pivot). But it's a little different than what you have in your question:

```
INSERT INTO flat
  ( id /* , other columns */, key1, key2, key3 )
SELECT id -- , other columns
     , MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'key1' THEN val END) AS key1 -- ELSE NULL is superfluous
     , MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'key2' THEN val END) AS key2
     , MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'key3' THEN val END) AS key3
 FROM item i JOIN property p
   ON i.id = p.oneFK
GROUP BY i.id;
```

That is, I assume you want the values stored in the `val` column and not the key indexes stored in the `key` column. By the way, I hope you don't have a column named `key` as that is a reserved word.

Hope this helps. This should work at least in both Oracle and Postgres.

Comment: really!? I'm very surprised, I must admit, but yes I can be easily wrong, I don't know anything about databases.

So joining two potentially million row tables is cheaper than few inner selects?

and sorry, the "then 'key1' " was fault on my side.

Comment: Those inner selects use joins too

Comment: well I don't see there any joins, just 2~restrictions. But ok, unless someone else shows up with different explanation, I can only trust you, and will follow you suggestion. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: @user1534084 - David is correct...depending your database type there could be some functionality that can simplify the code a bit, but this is the standard 'generic database' approach.  Just one note to add...David has left 'other columns' commented out...remember those other columns will also need to be in the group by clause if you wish to include them

Comment: joins are magic, as written they look like cross-products, but if the `on` and/or the `where` is simple enough the database usually finds a more efficient method (like an index scan).

Comment: great! Thanks all for explanations and hints.